# Unable to find CD-ROM when installing Office 2010 with PlayOnLinux

Tags: wine, microsoft-office

PlayOnLinux does not find the virtual CD-ROM it creates. If I choose `/media/cdrom`, or `OFFICE14`, or even `/media`, PlayOnLinux continues to display the error "Cannot find cdrom". It has no idea where it is mounted. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I never used PlayOnLinux but was able to install Office 2007 on Ubuntu through winetricks and the Office CD.
I'm currently using the latest wine installed through this PPA: 
http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu

I also installed wintricks with

```
apt-get install winetricks
```

There is an option to install Microsoft Office 2007 Pro. I have a Home and Student edition but it installed just fine with this option.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem installing Office 2007. You can start the install manually by choosing "Install a program not listed" this enables you to choose a later wine version instead of going with the default. I was able to install it this way.